# how can i add info to a DB with php when its being dynamically added with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have  a page that  adds checkboxes dynamically with javascript when i hit the add button, but on every add of the checkbox to the page i want to save it to the database . im just not sure how to go about doing that maybe ajax and php? i know how to make the insert its just a matter of getting it to call the function on every add.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
    addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
     txtName.value="";
});

$("#remove").click(removeCheckbox);
$("#save").click(myFunction);
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
 var container = $('#cblist');
 var inputs = container.find('input');
 var id = inputs.length+1;

  $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
 $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
 $('<br/>').appendTo(container)
}
```

html/php

```
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
   $hostname = "localhost"; 
     $database = "mydb";

     $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
       ?>

       <div id="cblist">

       </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add Checkbox" id="btnSave" />
```

Comment: Have you tried making an ajax call in your `addCheckbox` function? There are many tutorials on how to call a php page from ajax. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i just couldnt get it to run the ajax call in the JS i was doing it wrong i suppose

Comment: Show what you tried (edit your question with that info). More importantly did you do the most important debug step and check your console for errors? If there were errors post them as well. If you are using jquery, first check to see if loaded through the network tab and then check the [jquery api docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to ensure you called correctly.

Comment: can u send me any links that could help me call it , cuz i am not sure of teh errors

Comment: google.com - "php and ajax", "debugging with <your browser version>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

JScript (Jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addCheckbox(name) {
        var container = $('#cblist');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length+1;

        $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
        $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
        $('<br/>').appendTo(container);

        //some changes - start
        var newCheckBox = '<input type="checkbox" id="cb' + id + '">';

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                newCheckBox:newCheckBox
            },
            success: function(){
                alert('Ok');
            }
        });
        //some changes - end

    }


    $(function(){
        $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
             txtName.value="";
        });

        $("#remove").click(removeCheckbox);
        $("#save").click(myFunction);
    });
</script>
```

test.php

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$newCheckBox = $_POST['newCheckBox'];

/*
 * here's your server-side code.
 */
```